# Zend Studio Surround selected with php call

Tags: eclipse, zend-studio

I work with Zend Studio 10.1. I have many tags like:

```
<span>Days</span>
```

What I want to do is select **Days** and surround it like:

```
<span><?php echo $this->_('Days'); ?></span>
```

And because I use it a lot, I need a shortcut for this. I have tried to do it by code template like:

```
<?php echo $$this->_(${word_selection}); ?>${cursor}
```

But when I try to invoke template list in editor (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> on selected text) it states **No Template proposals**. I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the check box set in front of your template in PHP > Editor > Templates ? Did you set the "php" context on your template?

Comment: Yes and yes. I have it in my templates proposals, when I didn't select any text. When I select anything, the proposal is empty.